# Enviar imágenes a un servidor diferente que usa min.io

Tags: javascript, nginx

Tengo una aplicación que gestiona las imágenes a través de *min.io*.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que las imágenes las reciba otro servidor que será de almacenamiento.

Es decir, la aplicación esta en la IP `192.168.0.50` y el servidor de almacenamiento tiene la IP `192.168.0.60`.

He cambiado las variables a donde tiene que apuntar *min.io* pero me sale un error de CORS por culpa del nginx que no he podido solucionar.

¿Esto es posible hacerlo? ¿Alguna otra solución?

Comment: Tu frase "me sale un error de CORS por culpa del nginx" está muy equivocada. El error de CORS te sale porque tu navegador está tratando de protegerte de los ataques XSS más comunes gracias a las políticas CORS, y nginx no tiene nada que ver en todo esto. Te redacto una respuesta con una propuesta.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad (aunque sea tarde). Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tu redacción hubiera sido más acertada si hubieras puedo en cada máquina qué software se ejecuta y qué URL es la que usas para acceder a la aplicación que te da problemas de CORS.

Answer (score 0):

La aplicación [min.io](https://min.io/) permite configurar los orígenes autorizados en el archivo de configuración o mediante variables de entorno.

En la [documentación oficial de configuración](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-server-configuration-guide.html) tienes el siguiente parámetro de configuración del API:

```
cors_allow_origin  (csv)   set comma separated list of origins
                           allowed for CORS requests
                           e.g. "https://example1.com,https://example2.com"
```

Y la siguiente variable de entorno:

```
MINIO_API_CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN  (csv)   set comma separated list of origins
                        allowed for CORS requests
                        e.g. "https://example1.com,https://example2.com"
```

Te recomiendo configurar el parámetro con el valor "http://192.168.0.50" (la página origen de las peticiones).

Puedes abrir el API a todo el mundo usando "*", pero no es recomendable.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, mi pregunta es: ¿Dónde debería añadir esa linea?¿Donde se aloja la aplicación o en el servidor de almacenamiento?
Gracias.

Comment: Si me haces esa pregunta es porque no has dedicado los minutos que dije a la lectura del documento enlazado. Lógicamente es en el servidor de almacenamiento. Agrego eso a la respuesta para que quede claro.

Comment: Vale... El problema es que en el servidor de almacenamiento no tengo configurado nginx, ya que no aloja nada y min.io esta levantado a través de un contenedor con docker.

Comment: Ahora me queda más claro qué tienes montado. Parece que hay un problema con las cabeceras que envía el contenedor dependiendo de las variables de entorno configuradas en él. Échale un vistazo a esto: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/11111#issuecomment-772909514

Comment: Edito la respuesta para reflejar esto último.

Comment: ¿Pudiste cambiar la configuración de tu aplicación para que desaparezca las alertas de CORS?

Comment: Hola Oscar, lo he estado intentando pero no he podido cambiarlo.
Más tarde volveré a probarlo y te digo si he podido.
Gracias!